# Heat pump thermostat wiring, can I leave the Optional C terminal empty?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, heat-pump

We have an old Carrier Heat Pump system. The thermostat tells me that "C IS OPTIONAL WITH BATTERIES". The thermostat does have batteries. So I can leave the C terminal empty and use the black wire for other purposes?  (Three of the eight wires are broken.)

[image]

Comment: Is your C wire connected at the furnace end?

Comment: It connects to the backup electrical heater or emergency electric heat unit (the second stage heating unit?), or the Air Handler unit.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring at the air handler even?